# Setting up Jax-rs 2.2 with Jetty

Tags: java, json, jersey, jetty

I'm trying to set up some REST services on Jetty using Jersey JAXRS. I can't get json data through to my REST service class though. My ajax requests keep getting the "Unsupported Media Type" error and status. I get this regardless of what `@Produces` and `@Consumes` annotations I add to my methods though they should both be `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`.

I can't find decent documentation on Jersey and the loads of questions, blogs, and other resources all seem to be out of date. Looks like Jersey has undergone a lot of changes recently and I'm at a loss as to where I should be looking. I set up the following based on the jersey webapp archetype:

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.my.package.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Code snippet:

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

    // Plain text works!
    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String list(){
        return "Got it!";
    }

    // JSON doesn't work! >:(
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User create(User user) {
        Mocks.USERS.add(user);
        return user;
    }
```

My parent pom manages these dependencies ahd the second of these two is a dependency in my jax-rs project pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Do I need something to add support for JSON?

Comment: Perhaps adding a jax-rs Jackson dependency will resolve the issue: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Drew was on the right track in his comment. But the answer (for Jersey 2.2 + Jackson at least) was a more up-to-date provider

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Using this required no configuration. Use this with the two dependencies in the original questions and you're in business.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read a chapter dedicated to [JSON](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json) in the [Users Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html)? The easiest way would be adding a dependency on [MOXy](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy) and JSON support would work *out-of-the-box* (you don't need to explicitly register features the modules provides to make it work as opposed to other JSON modules in Jersey):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Anyways Jersey provides more modules that would help you with handling JSON media type:

- [MOXy](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy) (examples: [json-moxy](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/json-moxy), [bean-validation-webapp](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/bean-validation-webapp))
- [Jackson](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson) (example: [json-jackson](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/json-jackson))
- [Java API for JSON Processing (JSON-P)](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-p) (example: [json-processing-webapp](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/json-processing-webapp))
- [Jettison](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jettison) (example: [json-jettison](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/json-jettison))

Comment: Thanks This worked. I want to use Jackson and I couldn't find in the documentation where it explained the ```ResourceConfig``` class in the detail I would like but, but from the examples you linked to, and roaming the docs some more, I got it working. I created a class that extends ResourceConfig and registered the JacksonFeature class to it. I also added an ``init-param``` to my web.xml with a param-name of ```javax.ws.rs.Application``` and a param-value of ```com.another.package.MyApplication```

Comment: I later found a Jackson jaxrs provider that will hook up to Jersey automatically as opposed to the jackson module provided by Jersey which required configuration.

Answer (score 0):

JSON start working for me just with 2 dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```